# Sequential Circuits in IBMQ and Qiskit and generating a clock pulse

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, circuit-construction

I am trying to implement the Peres Gate with Feedback from Feynmann Gate feeding back into the third input to Peres Gate. This sequence needs to be repeated. There is also a clock pulse that needs to be simulated and fed into the first input to the Peres Gate.

Is the above possible with Qiskit and can it be tested on IBMQ. I am stumped on how to generate the feedback and route it back in such a quantum circuit. Are there any other libraries/frameworks which might be of help if its not possible using Qiskit?